# Return pointer to a function

Tags: c++, c++11

```
using F = int(*(int))[3];

auto *bar(decltype(foo) *a) -> F
{
    return a;
}

auto bar2(decltype(foo)* a) -> F*
{
    return a;
}
```

Why the first function can not be compiled?
I am so confused about whether the asterisk * should stick with the variable/function name or the qualifier?

Comment: Where is `foo` declared?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]; as it is you are asking everyone helping you to do extra work.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `*` before `bar`? Doesn't `auto` cause the compiler to use a pointer type if appropriate?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
auto f() -> T
```

declares a function `f` that returns a value of type `T`. The `auto` here is not a placeholder type. It's just there because that's what the syntax for function declarators with a trailing return type looks like [[dcl.fct]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#2). There is no type deduction going on when declaring a function with a trailing return type. A trailing return type is just an alternate syntax for writing an explicit return type that just happens to also involve the keyword `auto` but in a capacity different from its normal one.

On the other hand, a declarator like this

```cpp
auto f()
```

uses `auto` as a placeholder type, meaning that the return type of the declared function is to be deduced.

This

```cpp
auto *bar(decltype(foo) *a) -> F
```

uses `auto` as a placeholder return type (it adds a `*` to it which only makes sense when `auto` is used as a placeholder type) yet it also attempts to slap on a trailing return type at the end. That's just not how this works. You can *either* use a trailing return type *or* a placeholder type. Both at the same time doesn't make any sense. You either want a type to be deduced or you want to say what the type should be…

This

```cpp
auto bar2(decltype(foo)* a) -> F*
```

works because this declarator just declares a function with a trailing return type of `F*`…